# Processing an uploaded file server side (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've gone [this question here] ([How can I upload files asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery?lq=1)) and understood the whole AJAX file upload using JavaScript/jQuery.

However, unlike the example in the link above, my server script to process the uploaded data will not be a php file but a JavaScript file (e.g. called "chooseFile.js"). My question is: how can I read the contents of the uploaded file in "chooseFile.js"? I've tried to search for this everywhere but the information is all about uploading a file and not processing it.

Comment: You need Node.js server-side if you want to execute JavaScript server-side.

Comment: There are lots of examples of using Node.js in this fashion.  For e.g. http://www.componentix.com/blog/9/file-uploads-using-nodejs-now-for-real